# error " was not declared in this scope" c++

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include < iostream >
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n1, n2, resultado;
    char operacion(15);
    cout << "Ingrese número 1           ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Ingrese número 2           ";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Ingrese operación          ";
    if (operacion == suma) {
        resultado = n1 + n2;
        cout << "Elresultado de la suma es  " << resultado;
    } else {
        if (operacion == resta) {
            resultado = n1 - n2;
            cout << "El resultado de la resta es  " << resultado;
        } else {
            if (operacion == multiplicación) {
                resultado = n1 * n2;
                cout << " El resultado de la multiplicación es " << resultado;
            } else {
                if (operacion == división) {
                    resultado = n1 / n2;
                    cout << " Elresultado de la división es" << resultado;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> 4:1: error: stray '\303' in program
> 24:1: error: stray '\263' in program
> 29:5: error: stray '\303' in program
> 29:5: error: stray '\263' in program
>  In function 'int main()':
> 13:18: error: 'suma' was not declared in this scope
> 19:19: error: 'resta' was not declared in this scope
> 24:19: error: 'multiplicaci' was not declared in this scope
> 24:33: error: expected ')' before 'n'
> 29:22: error: 'divisi' was not declared in this scope
> 29:30: error: expected ')' before 'n'
> ```

otra cosa que quería saber si es que existe un tipo de variable para poner signos ("#$%&/%/%)

Comment: y cuando ejecutas esto que error sale? digo deberías empezar por depurarlo tu mismo y colocar aqui el error que te muestre por consola, no lo tomes a mal pero da muy mala imagen solo llegar y decir cual es el error? digo que haz intentado? revisa [ask]

Comment: ESta es la segunda pregutna sobre el mismo codigo. Que esperas con poner el codigo y no especificar un problema en concreto?

Comment: Perdon lo hare la proxima vez  .

Comment: de hecho hazlo en esta misma vez, dale editar a la pregunta y mejorala @meli09321

Comment: bueno cambio los tipos de variable pero me sigue apareciendo ese error

Comment: que aparece en cada linea que dice if y luego la condicion, no se si el error podria estar en esta

Comment: No haz declarado la variable suma, ni resta, ni multiplicacion , ni division, ni estas recibiendo lo ultimo que preguntas, y no utilices tildes en las variables

Comment: ahh me faltaron poner las palabras entre comillas ya que no son variables gracias

Comment: pero ahora me aparece este error .15:18: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]
15:18: error: comparison between distinct pointer types 'std::string* {aka std::basic_string<char>*}' and 'const char*' lacks a cast [-fpermissive]

Comment: seguramente tenga que ver con el tipo de variable

Comment: si operacion es de tipo char y estan comparando string. cambia el tipo de variable a operaciones a string

Comment: me quedo perfecto gracias por la ayuda

Comment: De nada, para eso estamos.

Answer (score 1):

Te paso la respuesta aca :

Errores que tienes

1. No estas declarando las variables para las operaciones que vas a comparar, o no las estas colocando como cadenas de texto.
2. No estas recibiendo el ultimo valor de la operacion.

```
int main() {

    int n1, n2, resultado;
    string operacion ;

    string suma = "suma";
    string resta = "resta";
    string multiplicacion = "multiplicacion";
    string division = "division";
    cout << "Ingrese numero 1           ";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << "Ingrese número 2           ";
    cin >> n2;
    cout << "Ingrese operacion          ";
    cin >> operacion;
    if (operacion == suma) {
        resultado = n1 + n2;
        cout << "Elresultado de la suma es  " << resultado;
    }
    else {
        if (operacion == resta) {
            resultado = n1 - n2;
            cout << "El resultado de la resta es  " << resultado;
        }
        else {
            if (operacion == multiplicacion) {
                resultado = n1 * n2;
                cout << " El resultado de la multiplicación es " << resultado;
            }
            else {
                if (operacion == division) {
                    resultado = n1 / n2;
                    cout << " Elresultado de la división es" << resultado;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Para utilizar string debes incluir : #include <string>

Answer (score 1):

He leído los errores y son varios: No has declarado las variables de suma, resta, multiplicación y división. Para ello, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
string suma = "suma";
string resta = "resta";
string division = "division";
string multiplicacion = "multiplicacion";
```

Otro error es que te ha faltado un **)** en alguna línea de tu código. Intenta poner la línea en la que te da el error para poder saber dónde está.

Por último, has preguntado si hay una variable para poner signos. Sí, la hay, es la variable tipo `char`, que la has utilizado al principio del código y, para el ejercicio que planteas, no creo que sea útil. Podrías crear una variable de tipo string `string operacion;` y no una de tipo `char;`. También, en vez de declarar las variables **suma, resta etc...** puedes poner simplemente:

```
if(operacion == "suma"){

    //Código.

}
```

En vez de guardar el valor en una variable de tipo **string**, pones el valor directamente en el **if**. De esta manera te ahorras crear más variables, aunque siempre vienen bien.

**AVISO**

Has utilizado variables sin declarar (multiplicación, por ejemplo) nombradas con tilde, es decir, **NO** declares una variable así: `int multiplicación;` Declárala con este nombre: `int multiplicacion;`. Siempre sin acentos o **ñ**, esos caracteres no están permitidos y son molestos si estás trabajando con otras personas que no las tengan.

Answer (score -5):

```
char   operacion (15) ;
```

sera?

```
char   operacion [15] ;
```

o mejor:

```
std::string operacion;
```

O como quieres definir la `operacion`? Si con las palabras "suma", "resta", etc. te sirve la `string`, comparandola `operacion == "suma"`, etc.
Si prefieres un simbolo `'+'`, `'-'`, etc, defines la operacion como `char` y lo comparas con `=='+'`, etc.

Comment: por favor no respondas a preguntas tan mal elaboradas y sobre todo que ya se publico antes, revisa la zona de comentarios y checa lo que le dicen

Comment: Hola @shadow. Es muy posible que tengas razón. Pero yo tengo dos ninas de 10 anios que estan empezando y no me gustaria que no las tomaran en serio si preguntan. Por eso dirigí la respuesta mas a que pensara lo que quería hacer y no a detalles de la sintaxis. Por cierto, puso los errores y sospecho usa un sistema extranito de pocos recursos.

Comment: el detalle es que en la plataforma se piden redacciones de calidad en las preguntas, nadie rechaza a nadie no te confundas pero lo justo es que si tienes una duda indiques que te ha salido mal y no llegues y pongas el código diciendole a los demás encuentren el fallo, ahora el ejemplo de que no se les tome en serio ocurrió con el OP por que es la segunda vez que pregunta y que no hace caso a las observaciones; lo justo es que quien pregunta se esmere